# Jackson YAML: parsing anchors and references

Tags: jackson, kotlin, yaml

This is a follow-up question on [Jackson YAML: support for anchors and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074700/jackson-yaml-support-for-anchors-and-references):
I had a tough time understanding how Jackson treats references (since they don't exist natively in JSON), so I wrote a test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import org.junit.Test
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class YamlRefTest {
    data class Item(val name: String)
    data class Config(val availableItems: List<Item>, 
                      val selectedItems: List<Item>)

    @Test
    fun testReferenceSnakeYaml() {
        val parser = Yaml()

        val test = (parser.load(testYaml) 
          as Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>)["Config"]!!
        assertEquals("test", test["availableItems"]!![0]["name"])
        assertEquals("test", test["selectedItems"]!![0]["name"])
    }

    @Test
    fun testReferenceJackson() {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())
                .registerModule(KotlinModule())
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)

        val config = mapper.readValue(testYaml, Config::class.java)

        assertEquals(1, config.selectedItems.size)
        assertEquals("test", config.selectedItems[0].name)
    }

    companion object {
        val testYaml = """
Config:
    availableItems:
      - &a1
        name: test
      - &a2
        name: test2
    selectedItems:
      - *a1
        """
    }
}
```

The first test passes, the second doesn't. From my understanding of the spec, if you just use anchors (without the merge syntax), YAML treats references pretty much as copy and paste. Why isn't this possible with Jackson? And if it is, what do I need to do to make this work?

This currently fails with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `undagen.YamlRefTest$Item` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('a1')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 9, column: 9] (through reference chain: undagen.YamlRefTest$Config["selectedItems"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

*Note:* Answers involving the correct use of `@JsonIdentityInfo` are helpful (I can't seem to grok how this translates to anchors).